# Can we remove Loading bar or 8thWall in a WebAR 8thWall App?

Tags: amazon-sumerian, 8thwall-web

On making a javascript node application with 8thwall and sumerian you get a loading animation of 8thWall logo , how to replace that with something your own. the project doesnot seem to have any assets of it in the folder

Answer (score 0):

I've not done anything with Sumarian bu that shouldn't impact this answer.

https://cdn.8thwall.com/web/xrextras/xrextras.js is the file that contains the details to allow you to update some of the 'free' UX elements that you get with 8th Wall like the spinning logo and the message on the screen.

You want to save the file and serve it from your own hosting, and then look for

```
<img src="//cdn.8thwall.com/web/img/loading/v1/eight.png" id="loadImage" class="rotate-center" />
```

... and replace it with your own logo (it will still flip it, so you probably want something mirrored like the 8 logo).